# send JSON request c# mvc3

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create an api for a movie guide mobile application, now i need to return json to the user containing information about the movie.

my request url is

/mobile/details/{id}

following is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    return View(kr.GetMovie(id));
}
```

GetMovie(id) returns an object of type Movie to the view which contains all the info;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use jsonresult as action to send data back

```
public JsonResult details(string movieName)
        {
            var data = new {
                               name="Movie name"
                           };

            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: no you do not view.. this will return just an object with data.

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult Details(int id)
{
    return Json(kr.GetMovie(id),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
}
```

As long as the Movie object is serializable this will work else you need to create a viewModel that will be a representation of your Movie object

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult Details(int id)
{
    var data =   kr.GetMovie(id);
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You might want to look at [web api](http://www.asp.net/web-api) also.

http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/739/ajax-aspnet-mvc-3